# checking cell value in csv and formatting in HTML using awk

Tags: awk, ksh

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f      
BEGIN {            
        FS=","          
        print "<table>"          
}               
 {        
        gsub(/</, "\\&lt;")        
        gsub(/>/, "\\&gt;")        
        gsub(/&/, "\\&gt;")        
        print "\t<tr>"        
        for(f = 1; f <= NF; f++)  {        
                if(NR == 1 && header) {        
                        printf "\t\t<th>%s</th>\n", $f        
                }         
                else printf "\t\t<td>%s</td>\n", $f        
        }               
        print "\t</tr>"        
}               

END {        
        print "</table>"        
}
```

how to check value of `$f` inside loop if cell value contains `"No"`  then how to print using

```
printf("<TD class=AltGreen  align=right height="17" width="5%">%s</TD>\n",$f)                     
instead of  printf "\t\t<td>%s</td>\n", $f
```

Input.csv

```
USA,NO,45    
UK,YES,90*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a couple of changes to your original logic in `Awk`

1. To remove the empty spaces from the `$f` fields, while parsing in a loop
2. Include check for `$f` to string `NO`

The `Awk` code I use as follows,

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        FS=","
        print "<table>"
}
 {
        gsub(/</, "\\&lt;")
        gsub(/>/, "\\&gt;")
        gsub(/&/, "\\&gt;")
        print "\t<tr>"

        for(f = 1; f <= NF; f++)  {

            gsub(/ /, "", $f)
            if(NR == 1 && header) {
                printf "\t\t<th>%s</th>\n", $f
            }
            else if ( $f == "NO" ) {
                printf "\t\t<TD class=AltGreen  align=right height=\"17\" width=\"5%\">%s</TD>\n",$f
            }
            else printf "\t\t<td>%s</td>\n", $f

        }
        print "\t</tr>"
}

END {
        print "</table>"
}
```

produced an output as

```html
    <table>
            <tr>
                    <td>USA</td>
                    <TD class=AltGreen  align=right height="17" width="5%">NO</TD>
                    <td>45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td>UK</td>
                    <td>YES</td>
                    <td>90*</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f      
BEGIN {  
   #header = 1   
   # for the no in OP and NO in sample       
   IGNORECASE = 1

   FS=","          
   print "<table>"          
   }               
   {        
   gsub(/</, "\\&lt;")        
   gsub(/>/, "\\&gt;")        
   gsub(/&/, "\\&gt;")        
   print "\t<tr>"        
   for(f = 1; f <= NF; f++)  {        
      if(NR == 1 && header) {        
         printf "\t\t<th>%s</th>\n", $f        
         }         
         else {
            # your NO filtering
            if ( $f ~ /^NO$/) {
               printf("<TD class=AltGreen  align=right height=\"17\" width=\"5%\">%s</TD>\n", $f)
             else {
               printf "\t\t<td>%s</td>\n", $f
               }
            }
        }               
        print "\t</tr>"        
   }               

END {        
   print "</table>"        
   }
```

- i just modify a bit your code to keep it the most as you do.
- use `$f ~ //`
- I add IGNORECASE, 0 for case sensitive, 1 not
- adapt your double quote for quoted value of HTML output

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks:
I think you want to replace `gsub(/&/, "\\&gt;")` with `gsub(/&/, "\\&amp;")`.
You do not need `header` when you check on `NR`.
When you want to check on "NO" in the header too, you can do something like

```
echo "USA,NO,45
UK,YES,90*" | awk '
BEGIN {
   FS=","
   print "<table>"
 }
 {
    gsub(/</, "\\&lt;")
    gsub(/>/, "\\&gt;")
    gsub(/&/, "\\&amp;")
    print "\t<tr>"
    if(NR==1) {
        tag="th"
    } else {
       tag="td"
    }
    for (f = 1; f <= NF; f++)  {

        if ( $f =="NO") {
           printf("<%s class=AltGreen align=right height=\"17\" width=\"5%%\">%s</%s>\n",
               tag, $f, tag)   
        } else {
           printf "\t\t<%s>%s</%s>\n", tag, $f, tag
        }
     }
     print "\t</tr>"
  }
```